# PHP MYSQLi loop through result set using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have this code here:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "pass", "branchdatabase");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT item.item_name, stock.stock_amount FROM item INNER JOIN stock ON item.item_id=stock.fk_item_id");

var_dump($result);

foreach($result as $r)
{
  echo $r["item_name"];
}
```

Which works as should, however the line at `echo $r["item_name"];` should not work but it does, as when I use var_dump to output $result it returns an mysqli object, so how can I index this in the foreach loop and output data? I'm just confused between how `echo $r["item_name"];` works when $result is returned as a object and not an array?

**UPDATE:**

After doing var_dump on $result I get this:

```
object(mysqli_result)[28]
  public 'current_field' => int 0
  public 'field_count' => int 2
  public 'lengths' => null
  public 'num_rows' => int 5
  public 'type' => int 0
```

Which to me is a object being returned, so how come I can use a foreach loop to still loop through the data like an array when $result i s object?

Comment: try $r->item_name;

Comment: No, the code works but I am trying to understand why. Because $result is an object, not an array, so why does it allow me to use a foreach loop to output the data when $result is returned as an mysqli object.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: mysqli_query returns a [mysqli_result  (represents the result set obtained from a query against the database)](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) which supports `Iterator` and implements [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php). i.e. can be used directly in a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd use a while loop to echo output the data.

Sth like this:

```
while($rf = $r -> fetch_assoc())
{
     echo $rf['item_name'];
     echo $rf['stock_amount'];
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand that but the reason I am asking is a friend was using the code I showed and I'm trying to figure out how it works.